# Using IntelliJ with Android plugin, rather than using Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I wonder if there is any difference between using the Android Studio, Google offer to use, and use the IntelliJ Base IDE, and install the Android plugin?

Would it effect the project and module handling?

Would it effect facets?

Comment: It's almost 2016 and android studio (despite it's benefits over Intellij IDEA) still has many bugs, and it's safer to use Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of today, Android studio actually functions, so I guess this would be my immediate solution. plus I'm not even sure the Android plugin would support all the features as Android studio will, and that there would not be any conflicts... better safe then sorry.

Answer (score 8):

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA 12 for Android projects for a long time. Android studio has a lot of beneficial additional Android integration, such as:

- Inline Lint API checks
- Drawable and string previews
- Better layout editor
- Built in Gradle support
- Better DDMS integration

But you can certainly just use the community edition of IntelliJ 12 for Android projects, and for production projects, I would say it's preferable at this time until Android Studio stabilizes. Also, I believe IntelliJ 13 will essentially include all of the Android functionality that Android Studio does, from what I've heard.

Comment: Did you try to use the same physical copy of a module in two or more Android project with IntelliJ?

Comment: Yeah, I've done it with ActionBarSherlock I believe. It can definitely be done.

Comment: can you please view this question and tell me if you think this can work with IntelliJ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845969/understand-android-studio-0-2-x-and-working-with-android-modules

Comment: I wasn't happy with the integration... I've turned back to Eclipse... I've found out why it kept crashing, and now it works wonderful!

Comment: IntelliJ 13 still feels very temperamental and painfully slow with gradle android builds. Even a fresh wizard-generated project is in the tens-of-seconds build time. Sticking with Maven for a few more months.

Answer (score 6):

This is useful FAQs about Android Studio vs Android Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.
It is clear to me that 
The EAP (Early Access Preview) of IntelliJ IDEA 13, which includes all of the Android Studio features except for the redesigned new project wizard and the App Engine cloud endpoints integration, is available now.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/

Comment: When I have the time, I'll try (again) to migrate my projects to Android Studio, but I truly believe it is going to take some time before people or big companies can relay on it, Eclipse simply had more time to evolve alongside the Android platform!