# How to improve android studio's editor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the android studio (in Mac) I have downloaded the Eclipse theme and use that.
I have the following problems:

1. When the cursor is on a line, the whole line is highlighted gray. But when I want to select something from the line (e.g. to copy/cut) the selection color is also gray and as a result, it is not possible to see what exactly I am selecting.
2. When I click on a keyword/variable, that one and all the rest in the file are highlighted in a really dark blue color, so dark that it is not visible to see what the highlighted word is
3. I am not sure if this in the same category as (1) and (2) but here goes. The graphical way that android studio displays that a file has compilation errors is really bad (eclipse is much better on this). I just see a red mark in the right part of the editor and the only way I could see the complaint is from the pop-up box when I put the cursor in the mark.

How can I fix/improve these points so that I am more comfortable working in android studio?

Comment: I think you agree with me that Eclipse is just plain better. Use libGDX with Eclipse so your code can compile on HTML5, Desktops, Blackberry, IOS, and Android. Then uninstall Android Studio and forget that piece of alpha software ever existed. Why would you want to use an IDE only designed for Android which takes away half the strength of Java?

Comment: @CodeCamper:Well because Eclipse is being phased out for Android?

Comment: I tried Android Studio for a bit and I guess it would make sense to someone who for some reason wants their games and software to only exclusively run on Android. I don't see how Eclipse can be phased out for Android when we have something like libGDX which so smoothly sets up my Android projects for me and gives us the libraries necessary to code for desktop and android simultaneously.

Comment: @CodeCamper Furthermore, Android Studio is *not* alpha software [since a couple of months](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/12/android-studio-10.html) now.

Comment: @NiekHaarman why would someone want to use an IDE that is exclusively for Android when one of the largest advantages of Java is that it is cross platform?

Comment: @CodeCamper you can have plain Java modules in Android Studio as well.

Comment: @CodeCamper:I like eclipse very much but for android development according to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html android studio is the official IDE

Comment: @CodeCamper and you know, there is also [this thing](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)....

Comment: @NiekHaarman What advantages are there to Android Studio though over Eclipse? libGDX has a nice little tool that sets up the Android project folder at the click of a button that pops right into Eclipse plus it sets up the folders so you can code for the desktop simultaneously.

Comment: @CodeCamper [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239732/things-possible-in-intellij-that-arent-possible-in-eclipse), and the optimized Android tools.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Exactly, I would rather use IntelliJ over Android Studio because it was made for Java in general and libGDX has a tool to set up an android project for that IDE as well. What optimized Android tools are there that we can't get in Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: @CodeCamper That's absolutely fine with me :) I can only find dated sources, but it seems that IntelliJ and AS pull in eachothers changes anyhow. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890766/using-intellij-with-android-plugin-rather-than-using-android-studio) for example.

Comment: @CodeCamper `Eclipse ADT` is no longer maintained and therefore deprecated. `Android Studio` has better Gradle integration, anyways. Also, it's not "alpha software", it's been officially released and **is no longer in beta**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the colors for the current line highlighting (`General | Caret row`), selection highlighting (`General | Selection background`) and usages of the element under caret (`General | Identifier under caret` and `General | Identifier under caret (write)`) in Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts.

You can also use Navigate | Next Highlighted Error (F2 in the default keymap) to navigate between the errors in the current file, and View | Error Description to see the description of the error under the caret.

Finally, when you compile your project (Build | Make Project), you get the list of all compilation errors in the project in a toolwindow below the editor.

Comment: I can’t find such an option in Editor fonts in my installation of Android Studio 1.1.0. I am using Mac and the scheme is Eclipse classic

Comment: I found in Editors->Colors&Fonts->General->Identifier under caret (and write) but it does not solves my problem. When I put my cursor the whole line is gray and when I select an element the selection is also gray so I don’t know what I am selecting

Comment: Edited answer to specify exactly which colors you need to change.

Comment: For the next highlighted error there is no shortcut key mentioned. I remapped according to eclipse